# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate fails without error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my schema:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    title: String,
    body: String,
    created_at: String,
    modified_at: String
});

var Post = db.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Now, I have a version of a 'post' in the database already. Here's what I'm trying to write (an instance of the schema above):

```
{
  title: 'Sample Post',
  body: 'this s a sample post.',
  _id: 50c208567d32d75f15000001,
  modified_at: 'Fri Dec 07 2012 10:53:42 GMT-0500 (EST)'
}
```

The ID lines up with the one in the database. This is the function:

```
Post.findByIdAndUpdate( post._id, articleObj, function(err, saved) {
  if( err || !saved ) {
    console.log("Post not updated: "+err);
  } else {
    console.log("Post updated: %s", saved);
  }

  callback(err, saved);
});
```

The console returns 'post updated' and the original post object without fail. The update is never written, nor are there any errors.

I've also tried wrapping the ID in `findByIdAndUpdate` using both `mongoose.Types.ObjectId( )` and `new ObjectId( )` (`var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId` earlier in the file).

I'm stumped. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should only include fields in `articleObj` that you want to update.  So you should at least remove `_id` from that.

Comment: Good point, @JohnnyHK. Another thing I've tried that has no effect!

Comment: There must be something amiss with `articleObj`; can you `console.log` it right before the `findByIdAndUpdate` call?

Comment: absolutely: `{ title: 'post title',
  body: 'post body',
  modified_at: Fri Dec 07 2012 16:03:57 GMT-0500 (EST) }`

Comment: It should be said, you're on to the same thing I am, because if I just put an object literal inline where articleObj is right now, I can get it to work. Example: `Post.findByIdAndUpdate( post._id, {title: 'new title'}, function(err, saved) {...` <- that will update the title.

Comment: From re-reading your post, it sounds like `articleObj` is an instance of `Post`.  If so, that won't work as that parameter to `update` needs to be a plain JS object.

Comment: Argh, I knew I was doing something stupid. Totally overlooked that. Thanks so much! If you submit that as an answer I'd be happy to mark it.

Comment: OK, I've posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `articleObj` is an instance of `Post`, you can't use it in your `update` call as that parameter needs to be a plain JavaScript object.